# R markdown, getting special characters bold

Tags: r, latex, markdown

I'm writing a R markdown report, but when rendering my script to pdf my header

```
### Numerieke beschrijvingen voor  $\'{e}\'{e}$n variabele.
```

turned out wrongly, the letter e with the acute sign did not show up bold, while the remaing part of the header was bold like, it should be.

i tried:

```
### Numerieke beschrijvingen voor  $**\'{e}\'{e}**$n variabele.
```

but it didn't work, anyone who can help me out?

Comment: Try `&eacute;&eacute;n` (instead of your code)

Answer (score 2):

It's again me, and here is my answer. It's just the Latex command for a bold text.

```
### Numerieke beschrijvingen voor  $\textbf{\'{e}\'{e}}$n variabele.
```